# Passing a custom IP address with Nginx proxy server

Tags: nginx, proxy

My apologies if the title isn't descriptive, I wasn't sure how to word this. I need to connect to a VPN, and need a specific IP address to do it. I was wanting to use Nginx configured as proxy server to do this. Here is my Nginx config file:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8080;

        server_name name;

        location / {
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
            proxy_pass http://$http_host$uri$is_args$args;
            proxy_bind 10.0.0.13;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

I had thought I could achieve what I wanted with `proxy_bind`, but whenever I try to connect to a website I am given an Nginx error page. I checked the error log, and I get an error saying it couldn't assign the address. I don't even know if that's actually what I want to do. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `proxy_set_header Host 10.0.0.13;`?

Comment: I haven't, no. I'll try it, thanks. Should it replace `proxy_bind`, or should I use both?

Comment: I tried both scenarios. I still got the same error when using both of them. I tried only using `proxy_set_header` and I get the error: "Fastly error: unknown domain: 10.0.0.1. Please check that this domain has been added to a service." no matter what I set the IP to.